# Is it possible allow other applications to retrieve data from our application?

Tags: ios, sqlite

Is it possible to allow other applications to retrieve(e.g readonly access to SQL Lite) data from our application ?

How can we provide some way of retrieving data? Please share your thoughts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, applications in iOS are sandboxed and any attempts to access areas outside the application sandbox will result in rejection during review.

There are alternatives, for instance sharing data via a web service, or using custom URL schemes.

An example of this is the `tel://` scheme that allows an app to pass a phone number to the Phone app and have it call if the user agrees.

You could make your app handle a particular scheme and other apps can implement that to share data with your app - vice versa will also work.

Comment: the above example is using custom URL schemes..ok, I got the idea. Thanks a lot Jasarien.  Let me know how can we share data via a web service ?.. how our application can listen for a webservice request ?.   (Our application will quit after 10 minutes of background running. right.)

Answer (score 0):

What about webservices? (XML-RPC or anything else...)

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webservice

Comment: Let me know how can we share data via a web service ?.. how our application can listen for a webservice request ?.

Comment: simple http requests over port 80/443